# Escalabilidad de ventanas en escene builder JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Hola amigos estoy iniciandome en el mundo de las interfaces en la universidad de la mano de JavaFX con el SceneBuilder. El caso es que me piden hacer una app multiplataforma (que el tamaño de la ventana sea escalable). El problema es que la ventana es escalable pero los elementos de dentro no lo son, y por tando a veces reduzco la ventana y se quedan a un lado y no se ven, Como podría hacer que los elementos también se escalasen en función del tamaño de la ventana? Me refiero a que si reduzco la ventana y dentro tengo un texto y un botón estos también se reduzcan. Muchas gracias

Me han dicho que use un AnchorPane pero igualmente no me funciona o a lo mejor es que no lo estoy configurando de manera adecuada.

Comment: y que codigo tienes? en swing se usaban los layouts, en JavaFX no me he dado tiempo de ver si existe algo similar

Comment: Para ello te sugiero usar siempre como primera opcion el AnchorPane sino vas a tener que agregar manualmente esa opcion a cada elemento que agregues en la interfaz.....Una vez que hagas eso te daras cuenta que tendras la opcion en Layout de poder agregar la opcion de redimensionar el componente segun sea requerido. SceneBuilder